# Difficulty with generic for-each loop

Tags: java, generics, foreach, iterable

I'm having trouble getting a foreach loop to compile.  I'm pretty sure it's a problem with my generics handling, since the error is an Object compatibility issue.  I've searched for solutions, but I can't find anything to fix the issue.

Here's the code where the Iterable adjList is defined.

```
public class Graph<V,E> { 
    private SinglyLinkedList<Vertex<V>> vertices = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
    protected class Vertex<V> {
        private SinglyLinkedList<Edge<E>> adjList = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
        public void addEdge(Edge<E> e) {adjList.addLast(e);}  
        public Iterable<Edge<E>> adjList() {
            return (SinglyLinkedList<Edge<E>>) adjList;
        }
    }
    public Iterable<Edge<E>> edges(Vertex<V> v) {
        return v.adjList;
    //... Edge<E> is also a nested class
    public Iterable<Vertex<V>> vertices() {return vertices;}
}
```

adjList is in fact iterable because a SinglyLinkedList is:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    //... 
    private class ListIterator implements Iterator<T> {
    // ... next(), hasNext()
    }
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {return new ListIterator();}
}
```

This iterator works okay in other situations, including other foreach loops.  Here is where it doesn't work (from the main method of a different class):

```
Graph<String, Integer> testgraph = createGraph("testgraph.txt");
//createGraph add some vertices and edges to testgraph
for (Vertex v : testgraph.vertices()) { 
    for (Edge e : testgraph.edges(v)) {   //<--- problem here
            System.out.print(e.getElement());
        }       
    }
}
```

The error is "incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Graph.Edge."

**Question:** Why is testgraph.edges(v) returning a list of Objects instead of Edges? I'm really at loss.

Also,

```
for (Edge e : v.adjList())
```

doesn't work either, with same error, and adding "Integer" in diamond brackets after Edge also doesn't compile. This does work, but I really want to avoid such horrible casts:

```
for (Edge e : ((Graph<String,Integer>.Vertex<String>)v).adjList())
```

Thanks very much for any ideas.

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't shown us all the code - but basically the problem is that you're using raw types. If you can short a short but *complete* program (with `vertices()` etc) that would help.

Comment: Ok.  I'll try to add relevant code.  Would you mind pointing out where the raw types are?  I think I understand what they are, but I thought I have used diamond brackets everywhere it lets me.

Comment: You're using `Vertex` and `Edge`, instead of (say) `Vertex<String>` and `Edge<Integer>`.

Comment: It is somewhat redundant to parametrize Vertex and Edge if they are inner classes of Graph<V,E>.  Perhaps you meant to make Vertex and Edge **static** classes.

Comment: What exactly does the `vertices` method return? Is it possible that you're losing the parameterization information somewhere along the line?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks.  But if I try to use `Vertex<String>`, I get an error: "improperly formed type, type arguments given on a raw type."

Comment: @Misha Or you can remove the type parameters from `Vertex` and `Edge` so they use the `V` and `E` defined by `Graph`. Your solution with static classes also needs to add `E` as type parameter for `adjList`'s return type to work. Either way, we need a bit more code to correctly identify the root of the problem. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring `Vertex<V>` and `Edge<E>` as inner classes of `Graph<V,E>`.  It means that every instance of `Vertex` is tied to an instance of parametrized class `Graph`.  So when you try to write `Vertex<Integer>` outside of a `Graph` instance, it means `Graph.Vertex<Integer>` for a raw type of `Graph`. That's why the compiler complains.

Your options are:

1. Declare classes `Vertex<V>` and `Edge<E>` as `static`.  Then you will be able to write `Vertex<String>` or `Edge<Integer>`.
2. Drop type parameters from `Vertex` and `Edge` and refer to them as `Graph<String,Integer>.Vertex` and `Graph<String,Integer>.Edge`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Vertex` and `Edge` without any parameterization, making them effectively `Vertex<Object>` and `Edge<Object>`.

```
public Iterable<Edge<E>> edges(Vertex<V> v) {
    return v.adjList;
}
```

Both `Edge` and `Vertex` are expecting to have a `Type` specified.

```
for (Edge<Integer> e : ((Graph<String,Integer>.Vertex<String>)v).adjList())
```

The above is **not** *horrible casts*, they are types where the generics are expected to be.

#### You have two choices:

Either specify the types everywhere or do not specify them anywhere, remove them completely.